# How to extract whether the text is bold or italic using PDFBOX api?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

Actually I tried with `text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight()` for extracting the bold / italic of a text but it returns me `0.0`

here `text` is a `TextPosition` object

Is there any way to determine whether the text is of bold or italics

Can you please share your views on it

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no sure *way to determine whether the text is of bold or italics.* The information returned by `FontDescriptor.getFontWeight()` is taken either from the font descriptor PDF object (in which the weight is an optional entry) or (depending on the font type) from the font itself (which may or may not have set this entry to some sensible value). Furthermore, a non-bold font can by double-printing or by printing with a big stroke value be used to appear bold.

Comment: @mkl : Thanks a lot mkl for your valuable response..

Answer (score 1):

```
text.getFont().getBaseFont().Contains("bold")
```

i do this in a proyect and works perfectly.

Comment: @Override 
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) 
    {
     
     
        System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + ","
                + text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale="
                + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space="
                + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width="
                + text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getCharacter());
          System.out.println(text.getFont().getBaseFont());     
    }

Comment: text.getFont().getBaseFont() returns a string with the name of font style that is using in the pdf.